# xbmc media library lost after system is rebooted

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfs, xbmc

I'm running OpenELEC 4.0 with XBMC 13 (Gotham) on Raspberry Pi.

I'm accessing the source via NFS which is shared (on my ubuntu server) as [instructed on wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=NFS#NFS_sharing_from_Linux):

```
/media/Large/Series     192.168.2.0/24(rw,all_squash,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

Adding e.g. TV Shows from the (above) NFS source (and marking it as tvshow) properly scans the subdirectory structure and builds TV Shows library.

**Problem is**: when the system is restarted (via Reboot), the library is lost and choosing "Update library" (from left menu) does nothing.

Turning on the "Update library on startup" changed nothing, too.

Only way to get the library again is to remove "tv shows" entry and create it again. But, I can't do that for all movies, shows, music after each restart!

After the library dissapeared (after restart), I've tried opening the `(~/.xbmc/userdata/Database/)MyVideos78.db` in SQLite Maestro, but it says:

[image: SQL Maestro]

I have also tried mounting NFS shares to home dir "tvshows" with `.config/autostart.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 25; \
mount -t nfs 192.168.2.101:/media/Large/Series /storage/tvshows -o nolock; \
```

The end result is always the same: library lost after system restart :(

Logs for your inspection:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7BtnBy2o_3vVU44YmdneDlaak0/edit?usp=sharing

dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/iXEtbr1L

Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought a new (SanDisk) SD card, copied backed up `/storage` data on it and the error is gone.

**Conclusion**: bad (Toshiba) SD card was the reason for library getting corrupted at system restart.